# Can't convert int to str

Tags: python, string, int

I am creating a project for a computer science class where i a creating a stacked cipher. I am using a copy to the clipboard function in order to allow the message to be changed by the next cipher. I encounter a problem with the second cipher, which is a substitution cipher. When i run it, it returns a "Can't convert 'int' to str implicitly". I have tried using str(message) but that doesn't work, and i have tried changing the code around. I am not good with python, so if it is a simple error, please tell me. What can i do to help with these errors. I have thought about changing the message to list, but how would i do that?

Here is the code i am using:

```
def main():
    myMessage = pyperclip.paste()
    myKey = 8
    ciphertext = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
    print(ciphertext + '|')
    pyperclip.copy(ciphertext)
def encryptMessage(key, message):
    ciphertext = [''] * key
    str(ciphertext)
    for col in range(key):
        pointer = col
        while pointer < len(message):
            ciphertext[col] += message[pointer]
            pointer += key
    return ''.join(ciphertext)
    print(ciphertext)
```

And here is the error i receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\project\transpositionEncrypt.py", line 38, in <module>
    Enc()
  File "I:\project\transpositionEncrypt.py", line 37, in Enc
    main()
  File "I:\project\transpositionEncrypt.py", line 10, in main
    ciphertext = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
  File "I:\project\transpositionEncrypt.py", line 27, in encryptMessage
    ciphertext[col] += message[pointer]
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ciphertext[col] += str(message[pointer])
```

This exception is telling you that it is not willing to convert an integer to a string, that is, it is not willing to evaluate `"foo" + 1` as `"foo1"`. To do that, you have to explicitly convert to a string. This is a choice that the Python designers make over and over, favoring explicit over implicit semantics.

Answer (score 0):

So, since you can't do it implicitly, do it explicitly!

```
ciphertext[col] += str(message[pointer])
```